# Disable span does not work on firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, firefox, html

how to disable a span using jquery/javascript. The script

```
$('#spanid').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

works fine on IE but doesnt work on firefox.

Comment: What do you mean by disabling a span? Maybe you could show the correspnondig html, too?

Comment: By disabling i mean that the span's onlcikc event should not be triggered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot `disable` a `<span>`. The `disabled` attribute only works for *input elemens*. What are you trying to achieve there ?

The only thing I can imagine is that you've got some event bindings on that `<span>`, to remove those you can call jQuerys `.unbind()`, `.die()` and/or `.undelegate()`.

```
$('#spanid').unbind().undelegate().die();
```

That would remove any event handler (bound directly or via delegation). The only problem here is, that you would to manually store the event handler functions if you want to "enable" it later on again.

Comment: This works only with Jquery 1.6. I have 1.3.2. This wont work for me. Is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for browser support. Although IE has only recently supported pointer events, adding disabled to a `span` in IE makes the `span` not emit click events.